# Efficient way to back up a git repository along with the current staged & unstaged changes?

Tags: git

I'm looking for a more efficient / fast way to make a temporary copy of a git project before starting to make crazy git commands. Yes, git never deletes things, and they can be recovered, but sometimes it will take a lot of figuring out, especially if you have uncommitted changes, so it's just easier to make a copy, and if things go south, then copy from there.

I'd like to copy the git repository itself, the changes in the working directory, to preserve what is staged and unstaged, but to leave out whatever is .gitignored, as those files are generated by the build system, and can be regenerated from the sources.

I tried `rsync -avz project project.2 --filter ":- .gitignore"`, but apparantly it did not copy everything, after doing a `git status` in the newly made copy, git reports files missing, and some type changes - which is wierd, but that's the result...

Comment: So, you do not actually mean "backup" in the usual IT sense, but you actually want to save away temporary changes because you intend to come back and continue with them later?

Comment: Yep, exactly @j6t

Comment: I also tried `git clone olddir newdir`, but that doesn't bring the local changes (not sure about stashes either)

Comment: You do not need a "backup". There are many tools in the Git toolbox that help your case. Use `git stash`. Make temporary branches. Do not keep your changes unstaged, but make frequent small commits. Use `git cherry-pick -n` or `git diff A B | git apply` to transfer changes. Use `git rebase` to clean up your history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's the more efficient but it's an easy one to do...

## Backup

1. `git stash --include-untracked` (or with the shorthand `-u`)

Or `git stash --all` which stashes all files, depending on what you want to save...

2. `git gc` (no mandatory but to make the copy faster)
3. Copy/rsync only the `.git` folder (that now contains everything to be able to restore the working directory in the exact same state) in another empty directory

## Restore

In the backup directory or after copying back the `.git` folder:

4. `git reset --hard Head` # restore all files
5. `git stash pop` # restore uncommitted changes

Comment: Will this preserve what is staged and what is unstaged? (And not mix them up when unstaging?)

Comment: @ÁkosVandra-Meyer yes. But check yourself as there is no risk *AS LONG AS YOU DO YOUR TESTING IN THE BACKUPED REPOSITORY*

Comment: Looks like the focus should not be so much on the "backup+restore" aspect, but more on how to keep track of a set of possibly unrelated changes.

Comment: @Philippe : it should be `5. git stash pop --index` (to restore the staged content in the correct place)

Comment: Note that the `git stash save` / `git stash push` operation ends with a `git reset --hard` itself, so that there's nothing staged or unstaged at that point (and with `-u` or `-a`, a `git clean` with appropriate options as well). So after your `git gc` and rsync you don't need step 4. But as @LeGEC noted, you must use `--index` at step 5. Personally I would not do any of this; it does not work when you are in the middle of a conflicted merge, for instance.